# SoundPool and MediaPlayer set the same volume but sounds different

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, volume, soundpool

I'm playing a m4a format sound in my android device, I both use `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool` and set volume to the same value, but sounds different!

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1); 
...start to play...

SoundPool mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,5);
steamID...
mSoundPool.setVolume(steamID, 1, 1);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: [MediaPlayer.setVolume(float,float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)) API is recommended for balancing the output of audio streams within an application. Unless you are writing an application to control user settings, this API should be used in preference to [setStreamVolume(int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)) which sets the volume of ALL streams of a particular type.

Comment: `MediaPlayer`'s volume is logarithmic. Perhaps `SoundPool`'s volume is linear.